# Loader.js:1017 throw err;

Tags: javascript, git-bash

I keep running into the code:
interna/modules/cjs/loadrer.js:1017
throw err;

while doing the download postman activity on codecademy. I can not figure out what this code means or how to fix it. I have tried other solutions that may be related but i still get the same error, even when I have re downloaded the project and re-started my computer, would anyone know what this code means?

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve]?

Comment: I can not actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command:

```
npm i core-util-is
```

Also install latest npm by running this:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: After I put in both commands I still got the same error message.